# Visa Transit in South Korea

Tags: visas, south-korea, indonesian-citizens

I'm an Indonesia passport holder, currently living in Japan with a working visa.
I will be travelling to Vietnam.

On my flight back to Japan, I will leave from Vietnam to South Korea, Incheon and then to Japan.
The layover is 5 hours.
Do I need a transit visa under my condition?

Answer (score 6):

You have 24 hours of visa free time as you have a confirmed onwards ticket booked.

> Passengers transiting through Seoul (ICN) with a confirmed onward
>   ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay
>   in the international transit area of the airport and have documents
>   required for the next destination.

[Source](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b)